# SetSPN using powershell to run CMD commands

Tags: powershell, command-line, cmd, powershell-cmdlet, spn

I am trying to make a script that runs some cmd command to set SPN:  something in effect of for each item in my list run  setspn -s  (name of the spn)  domain\service account  but I have a hard time running command line as well as i need to be  able to change (name of SPN as i go though the list)

```
$List = Get-Content C:\Users\MyComputer\Desktop\Lists.txt
foreach($PN in $List){
$Semper_fi = @' 
cmd.exe /C setspn –S "some SPN name\corp.com:1000" corporatedomain\ServiceAccount1                                                                            
'@
Invoke-Expression -Command:$Semper_fi
}
```

-S is suppose to look in AD and if the name doesn't exist adds or otherwise moves to next item and so on. 
 but it gives me an error:
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Unknown paramet...eck your           usage.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

so it would like this 
for every name in the list:
        (check to see if not in ad add this)         (this SPN)
setspn    -s                                    serverSQL1/pop1.company.com:2500

(under this service account)
Domain\Service100

and keep going until done.

Comment: the actual command that i can run in cmd is: setspn –A  "MySQL/PM1.corp.com:2643"  domain\serviceacccount.                                                    the -A is a switch that can be -S and -D and s on. i need to be able to run this command using powershell.

Comment: Why use cmd.exe? Just run setspn.exe. [This article](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/running-executables-powershell) has a utility called `showargs.exe` that will let you see the command line PowerShell constructs and some tips that will help you create the setspn.exe command line correctly in PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only issue with your syntax is that you need to drop the `:` from your invoke expression as it is not called for in the cmdlet specification. Then you can put in your name from the list by replacing "some SPN name" with `$($PN)`.

however you can clean up your loop if you drop invoke-expression entirely and use the call operator `&` instead.  In that case you would replace the entirety of the inside of your foreach loop with
    `& cmd.exe /C setspn –S $PN\corp.com:1000 corporatedomain\ServiceAccount1`

I'm about 90% that should work but I don't have a test environment where I can muck around with SPN's available right now so I can't confirm, if you get any kind of error please let me know and I will try and help you sort it out.

Comment: it doesn't work. gives the same error again  so my code looks like this: $List = Get-Content C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\Lists.txt
foreach($PN in $List){
& cmd.exe /C setspn –D  "MSSQ/PM1.US.world.com:2643" na\s01234
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the starter; it pointed me in the right direction. In the end, this is what worked for me:

```
$List = Get-Content C:\scripts\servernames.csv
foreach($PN in $List)

{
$SB1= "MSSQLSvc/" + $PN + ".domain.local"
$SB2= "MSSQLSvc/" + $PN + ".domain.local:1433"
setspn -s $SB1   domain\service-account
setspn -s $SB2   domain\service-account
}
```